# Populating TableView line by line in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I'm looking for a way to populate a table view from one single document, namely I want to load a .po file. 
I would like each line of my table view to load one line of text from the PO file.

Ideally, I would like to have one line in the first column, and the corresponding translation in the second column (to get a clear view of the contents).

I have not worked much with table views yet so please forgive my ignorance! 
I have done my research but I find the apple documentation confusing and very unclear -- and didn't find much online...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What’s your target platform: Mac OS X or iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bbum is correct, you don't push data to your table, you provide it and the table displays it.  Friday I did a quick mock-up on putting a text file displayed line by line, so maybe some of the code can help some.

Get a table view connected with an outlet to it's data source, then you can do something like this:

```
// Class variable in your table delegate object
    NSArray* lineList;
    IBOutlet NSTableView* table;

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [lineList count];
}


- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    return [lineList objectAtIndex:row];
}

// Be sure to use the proper encoding for your text file
// do something like this to load your text file.
- (void) loadData:(NSString*)ourPath
{
    NSError* err = nil;
    NSString* fullFileText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:ourPath encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding error:&err];
    if (err)
        NSLog(@"Err: %@, %d", [err localizedDescription], [err code]);

    if (fullFileText)
    {
        lineList = [[fullFileText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] retain];
        [table reloadData];
    }
}
```

In your case you may want to hold an array of dictionaries, using a different key for both versions of your text.  That way you can have two columns.  The NSTableColumn will tell you which column you will be drawing into when tableView:objectValueForTableColumn: gets called.  The other option you have here is making a custom cell that has two fields in it but that's probably overkill for what you're asking.

Note also that there are a number of other optional delegate calls you can add for more flexibility of how you show your data.

Additionally for more dynamic complex tasks I've found that bindings are better.  They can be confusing if you're not comfortable with them though.  For simple tables it's often just as easy to go this route.  Good luck!

Comment: slycrel, thanks for the piece of code, you are awesome. Thanks for the explanations too, that clarifies it a bit for me! I will try to use your code tonight when I get home and I will be sure to let you know. By the way, isn't there a library i have to include in my project, like libgettext.dylib or somemhing? This is another thing that confuses me, .po files are apparently GNUGetText format so i'll have to look into that, and also the encoding, and then figure out the rest from there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with .po files, so your parsing of the file here will likely need to change depending on the format.  Good luck!

Comment: slycrel, I am struggling BIG TIME here ! I cannot implement this code for the life of me. Not sure what I am doing wrong obviously. Is there any way you could provide me the example project for this code ? I would like to be able to save the edited data from my app as well, but this is all really confusing to me ! I will figure out the parsing part on my own or ask for help if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added my sample project here, you're welcome to have a look:  http://code.google.com/p/objc-textfile-loader/

Comment: You're awesome, thank you so much. I bet this is going to help me out a lot.

Comment: This does exactly what I am looking for. Now I just have to tweak it so it disperses the strings in 2 different table columns. So do you think that my app should be a NSDocument app or not? Knowing that I am going to work mainly with these .po files as mentioned before. My current project uses Core Data for storage but apparently that is getting in the way of what I want to do :(

Comment: Only use a NSDocument based app if you want multiple windows open at a time.  You can still use core data for storage if you want, it depends really on what you want to do with the data.  Best of luck!

Comment: OK, I restarted my project with simple NSDocument-based app that doesn't use Core Data. CD was indeed messing with my head, as of now I have no idea how make the best of it so I am not going to use. Anyway, since I have a NSDocument-based app, can I just use the code you provided in the - (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError statement? I am having a hard time figuring out how to use it with bindings in my table view in a NSDoc app... sorry to be such a pain !

Comment: You're probably better off starting a new question for that one.

Comment: Alright, thanks for everything slycrel -- I'm happy to find a helpful community whose members do not just bash newbies and their beginner's questions :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't push data to a table view, it pulls data from you.  This can be done with either bindings or by implementing the table view data sour (which are a little bit different, but mostly the same, between the NS* and UI* platforms).

The [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation both have links to examples and programming guides.  Read those and if you still don't get it, ask a specific question.

Comment: Hi bbum,Thanks for your answer. I will have a further look at the links you gave me and come back if I still don't get it.